# Differences between different creative coding libraries

Tags: libraries

I've worked with [Cinder](http://libcinder.org) previously under Windows, but have recently switched to Ubuntu. Since Cinder doesn't work on Linux (::sadface::) I've began looking for alternatives. With that in mind, could you please tell me what the differences between Processing, openFrameworks and Polycode are, and compare them to Cinder?

Specifically, I would like to know

- If there are differences in the *functionality of the packages* compared to Cinder (ie. one does something that Cinder doesn't and vice versa).
- I would also like to know how different the *syntax of the package* is from Cinder's.

I have already seen the following articles: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291769/open-framework-v-s-processing) and [here](http://www.creativeapplications.net/tools/) and have also visited the corresponding website for each of the libraries but could not find a clear and concise answer to my question.

Answer (score 5):

The things that come to mind are that

- Processing is the only one which is not C++ (but Java) in that bunch
- I think openFrameworks is the one with the broadest platform support right now (Win, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android, with raspberryPi incoming currently)
- Polycode is the youngest (with no judgement if that's good or bad)

Answer (score 4):

It’s good to stick with the platforms with a **big community** and **active development**. For me, this currently is **Processing** and **openFrameworks**. I use Processing because of it’s simplicity and openFrameworks for applications with high demands on performance.

Comment: Here is a discussion on [Processing vs. openFrameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291769/open-framework-v-s-processing)

Comment: …and here is an overview about different frameworks on [Creative Applications](http://www.creativeapplications.net/tools/)

Comment: Thank you, but I've already seen both of these. What I'm looking for is a concentrated comparison of all three, and how they compare to Cinder.